# how to grep range of numbers

Tags: linux, bash, grep

in a text file I have the following entries:

```
10.1.0.10-15
10.1.0.20-25
10.1.0.30-35
10.1.0.40-45
```

I would like to print `10.1.0.10,15, 20, 25,30`

```
cat file | grep 10.1.0.[1,2,3][0.5] -- prints 10,15,20,25,30, 35.
```

How do I suppress 35?

I do not want to use grep -v .35 ...just want to print specific IPs or #s.

Comment: it is not clear how the output should look like. Please [edit] to show it clearly

Comment: `grep` is on v `2.16` by now, so you should upgrade from `.35`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure if what you want is just printing the first two IPs, excluding that one with 35. In that case `cat file | grep '10.1.0.[1-3]0.[15|25]'` does the job.

Remember that you can use conditional expressions such as `|` to help you.

Comment: Note that your `grep '10.1.0.[1-3]0.[15|25]'` will accept `10x1y0z20@|`.  The x, y, z and `@` match because `.` matches any character; the `|` matches because `|` has no special significance in a character class `[…]`.  Even outside a character class, `|` has no special significance unless you use the `-E` option to enable extended regular expressions or EREs.

Answer (score 2):

You can use:

```
grep -E '10\.1\.0\.([12][05]|30)' file
```

However awk will be more readable:

```
awk -F '[.-]' '$4%5 == 0 && $4 >= 10 && $4 <= 30' file
10.1.0.10-15
10.1.0.20-25
10.1.0.30-35
```

Comment: Your `awk` variant works on the sample data, but should apparently include `$4 % 5 == 0` as a condition.

Comment: Thanks, yes that would make it safer.

Answer (score 1):

Note that the `,` and `.` in the character classes are not needed — in fact, they match data that you don't want the pattern to match.  Also, the `.` outside the character classes match any character (digit, letter, or `.` as you intend) — you need to escape them with a backslash so that they only match an actual `.`.

Also, you are making [Useless Use of `cat`](http://catb.org/jargon/html/U/UUOC.html) (UUoC) errors; `grep` can perfectly well read from a file.

As to what to do, probably use:

```
grep -E '10\.1\.0\.([12][05]|30)' file
```

This uses the extended regular expressions (formerly for `egrep`, now `grep -E`).  It also avoids the dots from matching any character.